# 'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, transactions, try-catch, rollback

I am trying to rollback a transaction with the following statement:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    IF SUM(Point FROM Players) != 4000
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
```

But I get an error saying:

> 'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name

How do I write the code in the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context use you `SUM` in is wrong. `SUM` takes a scalar expression, it doesn't use the `{expression} FROM {object}` syntax.

Use a subquery:

```sql
IF (SELECT SUM(Point) FROM dbo.Players) <> 4000
...
```